# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 7

Tags: java

Need a little help here,
tried several approaches to this but nothing works for me. I'm not sure if I missed something

**Code:**

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
hms1 st = dao.getRecordById(Integer.parseInt(id));
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String mname = request.getParameter("mname");
String datein = request.getParameter("datein");
String dateout = request.getParameter("dateout");
String roomtype = request.getParameter("roomtype");



String message = null; 

try {
    String sql = "update hms1 set lname=?, fname=?, mname=?, datein=?, dateout=?,roomtype=? where id=? "+ st.getid();
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setString(1, lname);
    statement.setString(2, fname);
    statement.setString(3, mname);
    statement.setString(4, datein);
    statement.setString(5, dateout);
    statement.setString(6, roomtype);

    int row = statement.executeUpdate();
    if (row > 0) {
        message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
        }
response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `id` (which is required by your query);

```
statement.setString(7, id);
```

And this

```
String sql = "update hms1 set lname=?, fname=?, mname=?, datein=?, dateout=?,roomtype=? where id=? "+ st.getid();
```

should be

```
String sql = "update hms1 set lname=?, fname=?, mname=?, datein=?, dateout=?,roomtype=? where id=?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should decide if id is a parameter so end SQL without getId:

```
 id=?";
```

And add parameter:

```
 statement.setString(7, id);
```

Or concat value without ? (less recommended)

```
  id='"+ st.getid() +  "'";
```